# How to read html from a url in python 3

Tags: python, html, url

I looked at previous similar questions and got only more confused.

In python 3.4, I want to read an html page as a string, given the url.

In perl I do this with LWP::Simple, using get().

A matplotlib 1.3.1 example says: `import urllib; u1=urllib.urlretrieve(url)`.
python3 can't find `urlretrieve`.

I tried `u1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`, which appears to get an `HTTPResponse` object, but I can't print it or get a length on it or index it.

`u1.body` doesn't exist. I can't find a description of the `HTTPResponse` in python3.

Is there an attribute in the `HTTPResponse` object which will give me the raw bytes of the html page?

(Irrelevant stuff from other questions include `urllib2`, which doesn't exist in my python, csv parsers, etc.)

**Edit:**

I found something in a prior question which partially (mostly) does the job:

```
u2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1')

for lines in u2.readlines():
    print (lines)
```

I say 'partially' because I don't want to read separate lines, but just one big string.

I could just concatenate the lines, but every line printed has a character 'b' prepended to it.

Where does that come from?

Again, I suppose I could delete the first character before concatenating, but that does get to be a kloodge.

Comment: Here's the description of [`HTTPResponse` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) in the Python 3 documentation.

Answer (score 126):

Note that Python3 does not read the html code as a string but as a `bytearray`, so you need to convert it to one with `decode`.

```
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()

print(mystr)
```

Comment: The `fp` object has `readlines()` method, at least in Python version **3.6.1**.

Comment: not a good idea to assume its UTF-8 encoded. You should try and read the header

Comment: I can't write mystr to text file. I get this error every time I run the program : `return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 369774-369777: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 119):

Try the 'requests' module, it's much simpler.

```
#pip install requests for installation

import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

more info here > http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: `import requests` is Python 2, isn't it?

Comment: what do you mean? import libname is used in py3 too

Comment: From the website: "Requests officially supports Python 2.7 & 3.6+, and runs great on PyPy."

Answer (score 17):

`urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()` should return you the raw HTML page as a string.

Comment: @user1067305 strange... `request.urlopen()` [returns an `HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib.request#urllib.request.urlopen), and [they do have](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read) the `read()` method...

Comment: OK! I tried it this way:u2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&ql=1')
junk =  u2.read()
print(junk)

Answer (score 15):

```
import requests

url = requests.get("http://yahoo.com")
htmltext = url.text
print(htmltext)
```

This will work similar to `urllib.urlopen`.

Answer (score 13):

Reading an html page with urllib is fairly simple to do. Since you want to read it as a single string I will show you.

**Import urllib.request:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import urllib.request
```

**Prepare our request**

```
request = urllib.request.Request('http://www.w3schools.com')
```

**Always use a "try/except" when requesting a web page as things can easily go wrong. urlopen() requests the page.**

```
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except:
    print("something wrong")
```

**Type is a great function that will tell us what 'type' a variable is. Here, response is a http.response object.**

```
print(type(response))
```

**The read function for our response object will store the html as bytes to our variable. Again type() will verify this.**

```
htmlBytes = response.read()

print(type(htmlBytes))
```

**Now we use the decode function for our bytes variable to get a single string.**

```
htmlStr = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")

print(type(htmlStr))
```

**If you do want to split up this string into separate lines, you can do so with the split() function. In this form we can easily iterate through to print out the entire page or do any other processing.**

```
htmlSplit = htmlStr.split('\n')

print(type(htmlSplit))

for line in htmlSplit:
    print(line)
```

Hopefully this provides a little more detailed of an answer. Python documentation and tutorials are great, I would use that as a reference because it will answer most questions you might have.

Comment: not a good idea to assume its UTF-8 encoded. You should try and read the header

Comment: @CpILL good catch. I agree, while utf-8 is widely used, you could potentially run into issues.

Answer (score 3):

For python 2

```
import urllib
some_url = 'https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html'
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(some_url)
print filehandle.read()
```

Comment: Might specify it is for Python2? As I checked `urllib.urlopen` is not there for Python3.

Answer (score 1):

I think the b'' that is prepended to the lines is to signify that it is a bytes string, which is what you asked for. To decode the bytes object:

```
b'Some html text'.decode()
```

It will decode in **utf-8**. However, it is best to decode with the encoding specified in the **headers**.

Im not sure if this works on Python 3.4 but this is how it is done:

```
import requests 
page = requests.get('https://www.mslscript.com')
html_text = page.text
encoded_html = html_text.encode(page.encoding)
decoded_html = encoded_html.decode(page.encoding)
```

To make it in one line of text is simple:

```
# Remove all the CRLF chars
while '\n' in decoded_html:
     decoded_html = decoded_html.replace('\n','')

# Remove all the extra spaces,
#   you could even replace with ''
while '  ' in decoded_html:
    decoded_html = decoded_html.replace('  ',' ')

# Remove tabs '\t', maybe not.
while '\t' in decoded_html:
    decoded_html = decoded_html.replace('\t','')
```

You can also make use of **requests-async**, a powerful library that is compatible with **Python 3.6** and is particularly effective when used in conjunction with **Trio**. Where as **requests** latest version works on `py -3.7`. You may want to upgrade your python version to atleast **Python 3.8** if possible.