# Grabbing data from sperate links of the same website

Tags: python, vb.net

Thank you for your time to read this
I wanted to know if there's any way that i can get a specific code from different links but they are all of the same domain i mean if i put many facebook pages links it gets all their names in a text file and each one in different line

Comment: can you provide some examples, it seems you want the sub domains of a domain.

Comment: Ok here the exaple
https://www.facebook.com/zuck
in this link if you opened it you will see the name Mark Zuckerberg
and if you opened this 
https://www.facebook.com/moskov
You will see the name Dustin Moskovitz
all i want is to program it to get the names from a list of links like this

Comment: consider using Facebook API, if you want real names from user link.

Comment: No no the domain isn't facebook it's just an example all i want is to grab specific HTML line from different links and put each one on a line

Answer (score 1):

I think if i understood you need the user's name form the link.

facebook.com/zuck

acebook.com/moskov

You can track this and extract the pagetitle, this may not be accurate always.

```
>   <title id="pageTitle">Mark Zuckerberg</title>  
>   <title id="pageTitle">Dustin Moskovitz</title>
```

html2text is a Python script that converts a page of HTML into clean, easy-to-read plain ASCII text. Better yet, that ASCII also happens to be valid Markdown (a text-to-HTML format).
https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text

if you want to read from the url check the below explanations
[How to read html from a url in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153519/how-to-read-html-from-a-url-in-python-3)