# I'd like to only source SOME of the api from a website into my code. I'm using python

Tags: python, api

Whenever I use the normal code:
`requests.get('https://example.com/example')`
I get the whole entire text of the website dumped onto the screen. How would I only source only part of the web page into python?

Comment: Look at [How to read html from a url in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153519/how-to-read-html-from-a-url-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, you can use another library called, beautifulsoup4, but if you want to use `requests` you can use regex to preprocess it before using so here is two examples

```
import re

def preprocess(string: str) -> str:
    string = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", " ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"$\d+\W+|\b\d+\b|\W+\d+$[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", string)
    return string
```

With **Beautiful Soup**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_clean(url: str) -> str:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    return soup.get_text()
```