# Unable to scrape data from a website using python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have used below [How to read html from a url in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153519/how-to-read-html-from-a-url-in-python-3) example for web **scraping**.

```html
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.realestate.com.au/rent")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()

print(mystr)
```

Above code is working fine but, when I used URL https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/list-1, I am not able to scrape data from the website.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Why not?  What happens?  What led you to think that was a valid URL?

Comment: is this what you're getting? urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests - If yes, you might want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python

Comment: I got the error 429 to many request when I have used 'https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/list-1' URL to scrap data.