# How to save a Entry Widget Tkinter as a variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, label

Im trying to make a application that takes in a url and in return returns that url back to be proccessed with tkinter. But I have tried everything and its not working. How would I do this I am trying to save the txtfld entry variable. I tried passing that variable through but it wouldnt work

```
from tkinter import *
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

# This is generating the tt_webid_v2 cookie
api = TikTokApi.get_instance()

window=Tk()
window.iconbitmap("unnamed.ico")
img = PhotoImage(file="dw.png")
label = Label(
    window,
    image=img
)
label.place(x=0, y=0)


lbl=Label(window, text="Sup", fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 16))
lbl.place(x=40, y=50)
txtfld=Entry(window, text="This is Entry Widget", bd=1)
txtfld.place(x=100, y=120, width=300,height=20)
txtfld.get()

# This is generating the tt_webid_v2 cookie
# need to pass it to methods you want to download
device_id = api.generate_device_id()
tiktoks = api.get_tiktok_by_url(txtfld)
# Defining mp4 bytes
video_bytes = api.get_video_by_tiktok(tiktoks, custom_device_id=device_id)
def download():
    with open("d.mp4", "wb") as out:
        out.write(video_bytes)
btn=Button(window, text="Download", fg='blue', command=download)
btn.place(x=210, y=170)
btn.pack()
window.title('sup')
window.geometry("500x300+30+30")
# need to pass it to methods you want to download

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: use the `get` method in some callback and there are examples on how to do this on this site and elsewhere such as tutorials

Comment: @Matiiss would you be able to give a example on how that would work

Comment: Where do you want it to process? If you tried everything I cant see any attempt here and no code that behaves differently as expected

Comment: You're actually making your question harder to answer by adding all the unrelated code to it. All that is needed is a [mre] with everything else removed.

Comment: @martineau no you dont understand I need it to get a video link and download it but its nt doing that

Comment: I understand completely, Call `txtfld.get()` in your `download()` function.

Comment: @martineau how do i do that

Comment: Calling it as shown will return the current contents of the `txtfld` `Entry` widget — which I guess is the url you want.

Comment: @martineau would you be able to give a example?

Comment: @Secretcode you have an example in the answer below, a very clear example, it even has a comment which says what to do next and where

Comment: @Matiiss it does not tell me to use the txt.get function in my download command

Comment: @Matiiss it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Matiiss Did you not read my message? I said im still getting  the same error

Comment: I can't because I'm unable to test the code due to the `TikTokApi` stuff you added (and I don't understand how the value in the `Entry` relates to it.

Comment: did you not understand what `# do something with url` means in the example below?

Comment: @Secretcode, you need
```url = txtfld.get()```
Then use```url``` wherever you need the url.

Comment: Sorry @Mattiss it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want the text typed into the Entry box. All you should need is the get method.

```
url = txtfld.get()
```

So if you are going to bind some action to the entry box upon text being entered and the user clicking return, you would have something like:

```
def action():
    url = txtfld.get()
    # do something with url

txtfld.bind('<Return>', lambda _: action())
```

Or a button:

```
button = Button(window, text="Submit", command=action)
```

Once you have the url stored in a variable, you can use the answer on [How to read html from a url...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153519/how-to-read-html-from-a-url-in-python-3) to get the html.

Comment: But i want it to get a url then it will download it but when I do that I get this error                File "C:\Users\dilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '.!entry': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://.!entry?

Comment: I have updated my code to @Steve

Comment: I have updated my code @Matiiss